# How to assign multiple values at once to multi-dimensional array AFTER creating it - in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, assign, multiple-value

I'm programming in C and wonder if it's possible to assign multiple values at once to a multi-dimensional array?
I have tried some technique but all have failed! 
I’m NOT interested to loop through the array to assign values (I want the fasted way to assign new values to all index in the array).
The array I’m working with: ary[4][4].

Comment: Can you show the techniques that failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an array is not a modifiable lvalue, it cannot appear on the left side of an assignment. You can initialize it and you can assign individual members via indexing.

> 6.3.2.1
>
> A modiﬁable lvalue is an lvalue that does  not  have  array  type, 
>   does  not  have  ...

And a modifiable `lvalue`:

> The  name  ‘‘lvalue’’ comes  originally  from  the  assignment 
>   expression E1 = E2, in which  the  left operand E1 is required to be a
>   (modiﬁable) lvalue.

So no, you can't do what you want.

Comment: You may want to add, "so no" to the end of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

memcpy from another one will overwrite what is already in `ary`.

```
int ary[4][4];
int another[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}};
memcpy(ary, another, 4 * 4 * sizeof(int));
```