# How to initialize 2-dim array which is a struct member in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
struct abc {
    double matrix[2][2];
};

int main(){
   abc test;
   test.matrix[2][2]={0,0,0,0};
}
```

I construct a struct called abc, and 2*2 matrix is its memember. But how to initialize the matrix in main function? The above code always comes with error... how to fix it?

Comment: You are technically not initializing in main, you are assigning. See these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981197/2d-array-values-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733919/how-to-assign-multiple-values-at-once-to-multi-dimensional-array-after-creating

Comment: You should include the compiler version and error message in your question.

Comment: try this also `test.matrix[2][2]={[1][1] = 0};`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan your code is not working..

Comment: Do you want to initialize it to be full of `0`s, or to some arbitrary set of values?

Comment: @SantoshSahu only  works with c99- read: [Strange initializer expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329206/strange-initializer-expression/18329258#18329258)

Answer (score 0):

gcc 4.5.3: g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra struct-init.cpp

```
struct abc {
  double matrix[2][2];
};

int main(){
 abc test;
 test.matrix = {{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
}
```

Or maybe simple is best:

```
struct abc {
  double matrix[2][2];
  abc() {
    matrix[0][0] = 0.0; matrix[0][1] = 0.0;
    matrix[1][0] = 0.0; matrix[1][1] = 0.0; }
};

int main(){
 abc test;
}
```

Comment: ur code does not work for me... same error occurs for the last line...i use vc++

Comment: You have posted neither your exact error message nor your exact compiler version, how much help are you reasonably expecting?

Answer (score 0):

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516657/c-structure-initialization) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181715/convienient-c-struct-initialisation)

You can write:

```
struct abc 
{
    int foo;
    double matrix[2][2];
};

void f()
{
   abc test = 
       { 
        0,        // int foo; 
        {0,0,0,0} // double matrix[2][2];
       };

}
```

I've added `foo` for clarity on why the additional set of `{}` around the array.

Note that this kind of structure initialisation can only be used with an `aggregate data type`, which roughly means a C-link struct.

If you really need to construct and then assign, you may need to do something like:

```
struct Matrix
{
    double matrix[2][2];
};

struct abc2 
{       
    int foo;
    Matrix m;
};

void g()
{
   abc2 test;
   Matrix init =  { 5,6,7,8};
   test.m = init;
}
```